# Why can't I static_cast a void* to a pointer-to-function?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, function-pointers, void-pointers, static-cast

This can be compiled (despite being UB (right?) because `fvp == nullptr`)

```cpp
int f;
void* fvp{};
decltype(f)* fp = static_cast<decltype(f)*>(fvp);
```

but this cannot

```cpp
void f() {}
void* fvp{};
decltype(f)* fp = static_cast<decltype(f)*>(fvp);
```

because (Clang says)

> Static_cast from 'void *' to 'decltype(f) *' (aka 'void (*)()') is not allowed [bad_cxx_cast_generic]

Why is this the case? And where from the standard do I understand this? I guess [[expr.static.cast]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast) is where I should look at; specifically [7](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#7), but I'm not sure.

---

[Follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74002860/what-is-the-c-way-of-interpreting-the-void-returned-by-dlsym-as-a-pointer-to) on the reason why I wanted to ask this one.

Comment: Because pointers to functions aren't guaranteed to be convertible to `void*`. Basically, there is no guarantee for a full-round trip between `void*` and a function pointer.

Comment: @JasonLiam I don't doubt your right, but I don't see _why_ that is the case.

Comment: Because code pointers and data pointers are not guaranteed to be the same size.

Answer (score 4):

This is not allowed because [expr.static_cast] does not allow it. Indeed, the [relevant language](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#5.sentence-2) is:

> No other conversion shall be performed explicitly using a `static_­cast`.

Since there is no conversion listed that would permit conversion from `void*` to a function pointer type, that conversion is not allowed.

The rationale is that function and data pointers may have [different sizes or alignment requirements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_architecture).

You might consider a `reinterpret_cast`, which [conditionally supports](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#8) such conversions. But it would be better to use a design that does not require such conversions. If you need to type-erase a function pointer, you will still need `reinterpret_cast` but can use e.g. `void(*)()` as the erased type, which is [always supported](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#6).

Comment: Since the list below your quote is fairly long and uses the word _function_ several times, I'd be curious to ask: what would be written there if this conversion was allowed? Something like _"`void*`-to-pointer-to-function conversion"_?

Comment: The language would be "object pointer to function pointer" or vice-versa, as in the specification of reinterpret_cast.

Answer (score 1):

> where from the standard do I understand this? I guess [expr.static.cast] is where I should look at; specifically 7, but I'm not sure

Basically, there is no guarantee for a full-round trip between `void*` and a function pointer.

This can be seen from [expr.reinterpret.cast#8](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#8) which says:

> **Converting a function pointer to an object pointer type or vice versa is conditionally-supported.** The meaning of such a conversion is implementation-defined, except that if an implementation supports conversions in both directions, converting a prvalue of one type to the other type and back, possibly with different cv-qualification, shall yield the original pointer value.

Comment: I would have thought that the verb _to convert_ in this paragraph referred to `reinterpre_cast`, given the name of the section. I guess I'm wrong. (Not that I had read it before asking the question, tbh.)

Comment: Doesn't it refer exclusively to `reinterpret_cast`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, but my point is that the round-trip is not allowed so i quoted that part.

Comment: @JasonLiam, doesn't it refer exclusively to `reinterpret_cast`-based round trip?

Comment: I don't entirely understand what you're trying to say. The bold part is likely intended to support rare platforms with separate code and data memory.

Comment: @Enlico As you said in your first comment, I think that the use of the verb `convert` here is meant to be general. Otherwise they could've wrote something like: *"`reinterpret-cast` a function pointer to an object pointer type or vice versa is conditionally-supported."* That is my understanding(which may be wrong).

Comment: I bet OP's compiler would accept a `reinterpret_cast` in this scenario.